# webiopi simple 3 wheeled robot, not functioning

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, rpi.gpio, webiopi

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "height = 300, width = 580, user-scalable = no" /> 
    <title>RaspRover</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() 
    {
        var button;

        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("bt_up", "/\\", go_forward, stop);
        $("#up").append(button);

        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("bt_left", "<", turn_left);
        $("#middle").append(button);

        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("bt_stop", "X", stop);
        $("#middle").append(button);

        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("bt_right", ">", turn_right);
        $("#middle").append(button);

        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("bt_down", "\\/", go_backward, stop);
        $("#down").append(button);


    }

    function go_forward() 
    {
        webiopi().callMacro("go_forward");
    }

    function go_backward() 
    {
        webiopi().callMacro("go_backward");
    }

    function turn_right() 
    {
        webiopi().callMacro("turn_right");
    }

    function turn_left() 
    {
        webiopi().callMacro("turn_left");
    }

    function stop() 
    {
        webiopi().callMacro("stop");
    }
    webiopi().ready(init);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        button {
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 30px;
            font-size: 18pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            background-color:yellow;
        }

        input[type="range"] {
            display: block;
            width: 160px;
            height: 45px;
        }

        img{

            width:320px;
            height:240px;
            margin-left:10px;

            left:115px;
            top:0px;


        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table  width=550px>

<td id="spacing">
    <div id="up" align="center"></div>
    <div id="middle" align="center"></div>
    <div id="down" align="center"></div>
</td>






</body>
</html>






/*** this is my python file... ****/

# Imports
import webiopi
import math 

GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Constants definition                               #
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Left motor GPIOs
L1=4  # H-Bridge 1
L2=17 # H-Bridge 2

# Right motor GPIOs
R1=19 # H-Bridge 3
R2=21 # H-Bridge 4

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Left Motor Functions                               #
# -------------------------------------------------- #

def left_stop():
    GPIO.output(L1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(L2, GPIO.LOW)

def left_forward():
    GPIO.output(L1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(L2, GPIO.LOW)

def left_backward():
    GPIO.output(L1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(L2, GPIO.HIGH)

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Right Motor Functions                              #
# -------------------------------------------------- #
def right_stop():
    GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(R2, GPIO.LOW)

def right_forward():
    GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(R2, GPIO.LOW)

def right_backward():
    GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(R2, GPIO.HIGH)

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Macro definition part                              #
# -------------------------------------------------- #
@webiopi.macro
def go_forward():
    left_forward()
    right_forward()

@webiopi.macro
def go_backward():
    left_backward()
    right_backward()

@webiopi.macro
def turn_left():
    left_backward()

@webiopi.macro
def turn_right():
    left_forward()

@webiopi.macro
def stop():
    left_stop()
    right_stop()



# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Initialization part                                #
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Setup GPIOs
GPIO.setFunction(L1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(L2, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setFunction(R1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setFunction(R2, GPIO.OUT)

stop()

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Main server part                                   #
# -------------------------------------------------- #


# Instantiate the server on the port 8000, it starts immediately in its own thread
server = webiopi.Server(port=8000, login="webiopi", password="raspberry")

# Register the macros so you can call it with Javascript and/or REST API

server.addMacro(go_forward)
server.addMacro(go_backward)
server.addMacro(turn_left)
server.addMacro(turn_right)
server.addMacro(stop)
# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Loop execution part                                #
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Run our loop until CTRL-C is pressed or SIGTERM received
webiopi.runLoop()

# -------------------------------------------------- #
# Termination part                                   #
# -------------------------------------------------- #

# Stop the server
server.stop()

# Reset GPIO functions

GPIO.setFunction(L1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setFunction(L2, GPIO.IN)


GPIO.setFunction(R1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setFunction(R2, GPIO.IN)
```

The problems I'm facing are:

1.html page is not loading from my custom location, it shows the default webiopi html page...

2. html page of [http://webiopi.trouch.com/Tutorial_Basis.html][1] is loading from custom location and working perfectly fine when executed.

need your help.. please help me out

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi part of the Stack Exchange network - I do have to say that this question would benefit from (further) editing - I am not that clear about what is going on.  IMHO I think you need to explain a little more about your situation - what hardware is involved, what have you done to configure the set-up...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening it using `http://[Pi's IP address]:8000/HTMLFileName.html`?

You sometimes need to explicitly mention your HTML file's file name. Make sure the Python file and the HTML file are in the same folder.

Comment: ya i have tried this. the method suggested by you is when you save the html folder in htdocs of webiopi.
my custom webpage is not loading even though i have specified the path in config file. it shows the default webpage.